# How to call a method on both (click) and (input) events

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I'm making a datepicker (range type) and I'm writing the logic for date validation for the same. I'm using `primeng` calendar.

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-mwpz39) for the same.

**timeline.component.html**

```
<span class="master-wrapper">
    <p-calendar 
      (input)="validateDateRange($event)"
      (click)="validateDateRange($event)"
      [(ngModel)]="value" 
      name="test"
      selectionMode="range">
    </p-calendar>
</span>
```

**timeline.component.ts**

```
validateDateRange(event) {
    console.log("validateDateRange called");        
   
    const dateRange = event.srcElement.value.split(' - ');
    console.log("here ", dateRange);

    let startDate=dateRange[0];
    let endDate=dateRange[1];

    // validation logic
    ...
}
```

Keyboard input event is working perfectly fine but the click event is giving me this error:

[image]

Please point out my mistake here.

Comment: I suggest to `console.log` the value of `event` in  `validateDateRange`. The `event` object will have other properties in case of a click event, and in that case the getting of `dateRange` should be handled otherwise than in case of keyboard event.

Comment: Output:

`event is  
click { target: a.ui-state-default.ng-tns-c4-4.ng-star-inserted.ui-state-active, buttons: 0, clientX: 1735, clientY: 408, layerX: 166, layerY: 184 }`

Comment: Maybe in this case `event.target.innerHTML` will contain the requested info, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Perhaps you are using the wrong callback events? https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/calendar Scroll down to events you'd see `onSelect` and `onInput`, I believe those are the two callback events you are looking for.

Comment: I've added a stackblitz. Keyboard input is working but mouse selection is throwing error: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-mwpz39

Comment: even with right call backs it s throwing error for mouse selection: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-mwpz39

Answer (score 1):

The click event actually gives you the date string instead of any srcElement.value as in a change event.

[image]

Check this stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-kgugzc

```
 validateDateRange(event) {
   console.log("validateDateRange called", event);
   console.log("Event", event);
   console.log("ngModel", this.value);

   this.dateRange = this.value;
   this.inValidRange = false;

   console.log("here ", this.dateRange);

   if (this.dateRange.length < 2) {
     this.inValidRange = true;
   }
   const fromDate = moment(this.dateRange[0], "MM-DD-YYYY", true);
   const toDate = moment(this.dateRange[1], "MM-DD-YYYY", true);

   if (!fromDate.isValid() || !toDate.isValid()) {
     this.inValidRange = true;
     console.log("either left range or right range is NOT ok");
   } else {
     this.inValidRange = false;
     console.log("both dates are ok");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with **(change)** event in place of (input)
and **event.currentTarget.value** to get value

Comment: Plz check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-mwpz39